# Android Studio - Add 3rd party library to your project

Tags: android, android-studio

I have to add a 3rd party library to my project.
Let's say the library is called XLib and it is made by vendor A.
I already have in my project a library with same name (XLib) but it is made by vendor B and they are 2 different things, I need them both.

how do I handle this scenario in Android Studio?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how are you importing these libraries? are they library modules or gradle dependencies?

if they are library modules, and you have the source, i would recommend renaming the modules XLib-VendorA and XLib-VendorB. Assuming they don't also have overlapping package structures, that may be all you need.

if they are gradle dependencies, then they should originate from different group names, so you would only be concerned about package collisions at that point.

Comment: they are both .jar files.  Interestingly, inside the jar file, there are some .css files that also have same name.  As I dont understand why would .css (StyleSheet) files be there, I deleted them and now renaming the jars works.  Thank you.